# How to get IDs not present in a table?

Tags: sqlite

I've got a list of IDs and I would like to get back the list of IDs that don't appear in any row in my table.

For example, this is my table:

```
item_id | text
--------|-------
1       | one
2       | two
3       | three
```

And for example if my list of IDs are **1, 2, 4 and 5**, I'd like to get back **4 and 5** because both of these aren't in the table. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to?

Comment: Because I've got some IDs and I need to find those not in the table. The IDs are UUIDs so they are generated outside SQL. Some (and their associated data) have already been saved to this table and some haven't.

Comment: Ah, okay. The easiest approach is probably just to `INSERT OR IGNORE` all of them (assuming the UUID is stored in a unique column of course). That way ones that aren't already in the table will be added and ones that are will be no-ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an outside ID list that is not stored in the database then you could construct a query like this by concatenating all outside IDs into a comma separated list of values enclosed in brackets (to place IDs into separate rows):

```
with 
  cte as (
    -- construct list of outside values in brackets here
    select [] as Outside_Id from (values (1),(2),(4),(5))
  ) 
select Outside_Id as UnusedId
from cte
where Outside_Id not in (select Item_id from ItemTable)
```

This is workable for not too many outside IDs.

If you have the outside IDs in a table `OutsideIdTable` then you can use

```
select Outside_Id as UnusedId
from OutsideIdTable
where Outside_Id not in (select Item_id from ItemTable)
```